# Eliminar input y dejar solo el primero

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una duda sobre eliminar `inputs` usando `js`, por ejemplo tengo 7 inputs y quiero eliminar 6 de ellos dejando solo el primero, intente usar `remove()` pero esto me elimina todos. gracias de antemano.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#unica-pregunta').change(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        var opciones=id.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)\-([0-9]+)/g)[0]+'-opcion';
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#'+opciones).attr('disabled',true).remove().val('');
        }else {
            $('#'+opciones).attr('disabled',false).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿qué es lo que estás intentando conseguir con esa expresión regular? Aparte, ¿tienen todas tus opciones el mismo ID?

Comment: No todas las opciones tienen un Id propio, solo puse como ejemplo ya que uso un framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto:

```js
$('#eliminar').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#formulario").find(".form-group").not(':first').remove();

});

$('#ocultar').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#formulario").find(".form-group:first").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form id="formulario">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Input1</label>
    <input type="input" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="input1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Input2</label>
    <input type="input" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="input2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Input3</label>
    <input type="input" class="form-control" id="input3" placeholder="input2">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="ocultar">Ocultar el Primero</button>
</form>
```

Si te fijas cree un formulario con 3 input, tu puedes colocar la cantidad que quieres y en el **js** si te fijas yo invoco al **#formulario** y luego le digo que encuentre a todos los que tienes esta clase **.form-group** y con el **not(':first')** le estoy diciendo **"excepto el primero"**, espero te sirva

Comment: Es justo lo que buscaba, mas bien quería consultarte a parte de poder dejar el primero como lo puedo ocultar intente con .hide() pero no me funciona.

Comment: Listo ya lo modifique para que te guies, no te olvides de colocar mi respuesta como correcta por favor. @MiguelAngel